# sAMAccountName and case-sensitivity

Tags: vbscript, active-directory

I'm able to fetch the user details for a particular ADS user through the following vbs code.

```
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
objConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection

objCommand.CommandText = _
    "<LDAP://"& objDomain.Get("distinguishedName") &">;" & _
    "(&(objectclass=user)(objectcategory=person)(sAMAccountName=" & strUserName & "));" & _
    "cn,displayName;subtree"
objCommand.Execute
```

Here could I want to apply `LCase` to `sAMAccountName` before comparing with `strUserName`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sAMAccountName` is case-insensitive, so it doesn't matter if the value of `strUserName` is in upper, lower, or mixed case.

Comment: Latecomer, but: Do you have anything that can verify this statement? :)

Comment: @Squazz You mean other than the obvious facts when you try it? Well, there's always [the](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc220838.aspx) [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684455%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).